# Instagram API getting JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, instagram

Ok so I am pretty new to APIs, I've been diving in brute-force breaking things. 
I am trying to get hashtag stats into a php variable I can manipulate in JSON format.

```
$key = "SOMEKEYVALUEIDIDNOTINCLUDEHERE" ;
$hashtag = "als" ;

$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$hashtag.'?access_token='.$key ;


$content = file_get_contents(url);
$data = json_decode($content)  ;


echo $data->{'meta'} ;
```

Here is the JSON data that pops up in the browser when I type the url in manually:
`{"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"media_count":1237544,"name":"als"}}`

The echo I included is the the only attempt I made at displaying the "What I thought would be returned JSON Code". The echo is always empty.

How can I go about solving this? I've heard of cURL and read about it, but don't have a really good grasp of what it is.

Thanks!

Comment: `echo $data->meta->data->media_count` ?

Comment: When in doubt, dump your variable out with `var_dump($data);` or `print_r($data);`. Also, `json_decode` returns an object. If you want it to return an array, do this: `json_decode($content, true);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access your data like this:

```
echo $data->meta->code // 200
echo $data->data->meta_count // 1237544
echo $data->data->name // als
```